# Trying to find a way to make new columns with JS

Tags: javascript

I am building a table with JavaScript. If you check the link you can see it is all in one column, but I need the name. prices, and images in separate columns. I am honestly not sure where to start to do this, so I'm looking for some help.

https://jsfiddle.net/wL28gd10/

JS

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
// ARRAYs
var itemName = ["BLT", "PBJ", "TC", "HC", "GC"];
var itemPrice = ["$1", "$2", "$3", "$4", "$5"];
var itemPhoto = 
["images/blt.jpg","images/pbj.jpg","images/tc.jpg","images/hc.jpg","images/gc.jpg"];

//Create HTML Table
var perrow = 1, 
   table = document.createElement("table"),
   row = table.insertRow();

// Loop through itemName array 
 for (var i = 0; i < itemName.length; i++) {

// Add cell
 var cell = row.insertCell();
 cell.innerHTML = itemName[i];

// Brreak into next row
 var next = i + 1;
 if (next%perrow==0 && next!=itemName.length) {
   row = table.insertRow();
 }
}

// Loop through itemPrice array
 for (var i = 0; i < itemPrice.length; i++) {

// Add cell
 var cell = row.insertCell();
 cell.innerHTML = itemPrice[i];

 // Break into next row
 var next = i + 1;
 if (next%perrow==0 && next!=itemPrice.length) {
   row = table.insertRow();
 }
}

// Loop through itemPhoto array
 for (var i = 0; i < itemPhoto.length; i++) {

 // Add cell
  var cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.innerHTML = itemPhoto[i];

  // Break into next row
  var next = i + 1;
  if (next%perrow==0 && next!=itemPhoto.length) {
    row = table.insertRow();
  }
}


// Attach table to HTML id "menu-table"
 document.getElementById("menu-table").appendChild(table);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create all of your columns in one loop, like:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < itemName.length; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow();
  // Add cell
  var cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.innerHTML = itemName[i];
  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.innerHTML = itemPrice[i]; 
  // Add cell
  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.innerHTML = itemPhoto[i];
}
```

Comment: Where in the JS should i place this?

Comment: get rid of your other loops and replace those with this instead

Comment: This does the opposite though. Now it is all in one row. Each row should have a name, a price, and the images link.

Comment: just moe your insertRow call inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You only really need one loop.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
   // ARRAYs
   var itemName = ["BLT", "PBJ", "TC", "HC", "GC"];
   var itemPrice = ["$1", "$2", "$3", "$4", "$5"];
   var itemPhoto = ["images/blt.jpg","images/pbj.jpg","images/tc.jpg","images/hc.jpg","images/gc.jpg"];
 
   //Create HTML Table
   var perrow = 1, 
       table = document.createElement("table");
       
 
   // Loop through itemName array 
   for (var i = 0; i < itemName.length; i++) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    // Add cell
    var cell = row.insertCell();
     cell.innerHTML = itemName[i];
     var cell = row.insertCell();
     cell.innerHTML = itemPrice[i];
     var cell = row.insertCell();
     cell.innerHTML = itemPhoto[i]; 
    
   }

   // Attach table to HTML id "menu-table"
   document.getElementById("menu-table").appendChild(table);
 });
```

```css
      table { border-collapse: collapse; }

      table tr td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
      }
```

```html
<div id="menu-table"></div>
```